# Reading BMP headers, packed. Reading incorrect values

Tags: c, struct, bmp, pack

I've recently made a program to read the fileheader and infoheader of a BMP file. I packed them as shown, fread them, and print the width and height. Unfortunatly the width and height come up as incorrect. I'm not sure why. Perhaps a bit/little endian issue? If so I don't know how to fix it. I'm compiling and running it on GCC.

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char fileMarker1;       /* 'B' */                       
    unsigned char fileMarker2;       /* 'M' */ 
    unsigned int   bfSize;             
    unsigned short unused1;           
    unsigned short unused2;           
    unsigned int   imageDataOffset;  /* Offset to the start of image data */
 }FILEHEADER;

 typedef struct                       
 { 
    unsigned int   biSize;            
    signed int     width;            /* Width of the image */ 
    signed int     height;           /* Height of the image */ 
    unsigned short planes;             
    unsigned short bitPix;             
    unsigned int   biCompression;      
    unsigned int   biSizeImage;        
    int            biXPelsPerMeter;    
    int            biYPelsPerMeter;    
    unsigned int   biClrUsed;          
    unsigned int   biClrImportant;     
 }INFOHEADER;

 #pragma pack()
```

.....

```
 fread( &header, sizeof(FILEHEADER), 1, image );
```

.....

```
 fread( &iheader, sizeof(INFOHEADER), 1, image );
```

.....

```
 printf("Width: %i\n", iheader.width);
 printf("Height: %i\n", iheader.height);
```

Comment: What are the actual dimensions of the image, and what values do you get. Look at them in hex to see if it's an endianess issue

Comment: Is your system big endian? What is your system?

Comment: are you moving to the start of the image data before reading it?. the offset to the data is specfified in the FILEHEADER. Are the values for fileMarker1 and fileMarker2 right?

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header "All of the integer values are stored in little-endian format "

Comment: My positioning is correct, I spent extensive time checking this with lots or repositioning such as fseek.

The filemarkers are correct. I guess I'll have to check out the endianess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows bitmap file is indeed stored as little endian. Thus you will need to reverse the endianness of each 2 or 4 byte int value after loading, assuming that your system is big-endian.  This [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-) describes various ways to do that.